# How to Pass Dropdown selected value to Controller on Selected index change

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am new to MVC and i am stuck at one point into project i wanted to check the Availability of a Batch,i am using a Dropdownlist and it is populate by Batch table.

My Question is when i am selecting a batch from drop downlist on same time it will give Msg that Batch is available or Not.

Batch Table Structure is:
BatchID BachName TotalSeat AvailableSeat
01 L1 50 40
02 L2 20 20

i don't know how to do this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the different solutions form this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/593787/HowplustoplusPassplusDropdownplusselectplusvaluepl):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Method", "YourController")) {

@Html.DropDownList("Id", ViewBag.DropDownCollection as SelectList, "--pick--", new {
    title = "Pick Batch",
    onchange = "submit();"
});

}

ActionResult

public ActionResult Method(string Id)
{
 //do the logic here
}
```